# Run npm package from rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, npm

In my rails application I have a module that is running the following:

`system("osmtogeojson #{input_path} > #{output_path}")`

This works on my local machine as I have that specific npm package (osmtogeojson) installed. I have my application deployed on Heroku, and I cannot get Heroku to install NPM or my NPM Packages.

I follow the tutorial [here](http://blog.jasonkim.ca/blog/2015/06/29/setting-up-bower-on-rails-4-for-heroku/) and added a packages.json along with running

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

and creating a .buildpacks file with:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
```

When I deploy to Heroku, I don't see it running npm install with my dependencies, and my code that's calling the npm package does not work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried asking heroku for help? Might be your best bet here...

Comment: @TarynEast I haven't yet...not a bad idea. I'll reach out and post an answer if I get one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I had done this in the first place, but for the record this is what worked.

- In my repo I ran and walked through the steps for `$npm init`
- Added the npm package I needed with `$npm install osmtogeojson --save`
- Added my buildpack to heroku `$heroku config:add heroku/nodejs`
- Pushed my repo up to heroku `$git push heroku master`

Now it works!

Comment: The console says: "heroku/nodejs is invalid. Must be in the format FOO=bar."

Answer (score 1):

This article is a little outdated. You don't need anything like `heroku-buildpack-multi` anymore to configure multiple buildpacks. Besides, this project is deprecated. Remove it from your app and just add official buildpacks `heroku/nodejs` and `heroku/ruby`. It is usually a good idea to add nodejs first. Then try to re-deploy your application.

If it does not work, try to login into your application dyno with `heroku run bash` and verify that you actually have package.json. Check if it is not ignored somewhere, like in `.gitignore` or `.slugignore`.

If it still does not work, it is possible that you added required package as dev dependency. If so, set config variable `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` to `false`.

Hope this helps.